# Unregister service workers where script contains specific word programatically

Tags: service-worker

I have visited a lot of sites and they have created a lot of service workers for me. When I visit chrome://serviceworker-internals/ I see that I need to unregister a lot of service workers where script url contains specific word.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use this function:

```js
function unregisterServiceWorkersWhereScriptContainSpecificWord(specificWord) {
  const allServiceWorkerDivs = [
    ...document.body.querySelectorAll('.serviceworker-item'),
  ];
  const serviceWorkerDivsWhichContainSpecificWord = allServiceWorkerDivs.filter(
    (div) => {
      const scriptDiv = div.querySelector('.serviceworker-script_url');
      return scriptDiv.textContent.includes(specificWord);
    }
  );
  const unregisterButtons = serviceWorkerDivsWhichContainSpecificWord.map(
    (div) => {
      return div.querySelector('button.unregister');
    }
  );
  unregisterButtons.forEach((button) => {
    button.click();
  });
}
```

It gets specific word which must be located in text content of service worker div element and then clicks unregister button for every service worker

Note that this function should be defined and called in your browser console